# The constructor is undefined error when trying to make new object

Tags: java

just check out my code, why is this not working? just trying to create new student object using the Student method.

```
public class Student {

    public String id, first_name,last_name;
    //assuming it was subject grades
    public String[] subject_grades;

    public void Student(String id, String first_name, String last_name, String[] subject_grades) {
        this.id = id;
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.subject_grades = subject_grades;
    }

    public static boolean readFile(String filename) { File file = new File(filename);
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
                String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
                new Student(words[0], words[1], words[2],
                            new String[] {words[3], words[4], words[5], words[6], words[7], words[8]}
                ));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to read file");
        }

        return true;

    }

}
```

the constructor is undefined.

Comment: error is at the new student line.

Comment: `public void Student(...)` - not a constructor. `public Student(...)` - a constructor

Comment: It looks like you have one closing bracket too much at the call to the constructor, which isn't defined (see answers and other comments).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public void Student(String id,String first_name,String last_name,String[] subject_grades) {
```

This is not a constructor. It is a `void` method called `Student`.

Change it to

```
 public Student(String id,String first_name,String last_name,String[] subject_grades) {
```

Comment: ahh sorry so simple!